# Web.config Redirect to http://www.example.com to https://example.com

Tags: iis, https, web-config

I want to redirect http://www.example.com, http://example.com or https://www.example.com to https://example.com. How do I do this with a web.config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the URL Rewrite module (it doesn't install by default). http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Once you have that, you can set up a rules section in your web.config under system.webServer/rewrite/rules. Add this rule:

```
<rule name="Redirect www to domain" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
           <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
           <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.example.com" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: I had other rules and realized I had to place it at the top and set stopProcessing="false".