# Http redirection loop Issue - IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis

In IIS 7.5, using global.asax, I intend to redirect as follows.

The scenario is this, 1. http + domainname should be redirected to https + www + domainname.

2. http + www + domainname should be redirected to https + www + domainname.

Code below

```
string currentUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
    string newURL = currentUrl;
            try
            {
                Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                newURL = newURL.Replace("http://domainname", "https://www.domainname");
                newURL = newURL.Replace("http://www.domainname", "https://www.domainname");

                Response.AddHeader("Location", newURL);
                Response.End();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

It gets into an infinite redirect loop and it doesn't load the site at all. Can someone please help?

[Click here to view Site Binding screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1ewH.png)

Comment: Best thing to do is use your web.config to do both of this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39478821/web-config-redirect-to-http-www-example-com-to-https-example-com

Comment: I did that. I am still getting that issue.Can you please advice if there is something wrong with  my binding?(Check new image updated)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to check, after currentUrl is assigned, whether it is in the format you desire -- https + www + domainname . If it isn't then do your redirect code, but if it's already correct, skip the redirect stuff.

Comment: I did that. It is still the same. Is there anything wrong with the binding. Kindly help. https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1ewH.png

Comment: Could you post the code where you are checking whether the current url is in the correct format? Based on the code above, you're redirecting any request that comes in regardless of whether it's in the right format.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with IIS rewrite module, that will be cleaner.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module